# How to pass through the progress monitor to several subroutines?

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-plugin, eclipse-rcp, progressmonitor

Suppose I have an API method which is intended to perform long-term operation and which therefore receives monitor as a parameter, like in

```
org.eclipse.ui.part.EditorPart.doSave(IProgressMonitor monitor)
```

If I had single operation to do in this method, I would code, for instance, to write an image

```
imageFile.create(imageInput, false, monitor);
```

But what if I do SEVERAL long-term sub-routines inside single `doSave`? How to make that monitor measures each with 50% or something?

```
imageFile.create(imageInput, false, monitor);
descriptionFile.create(descriptionInput, false, monitor);
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use `SubProgressMonitor` for each call the methods:

```java
monitor.beginText("task", 100);

imageFile.create(imageInput, false, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 50));

descriptionFile.create(descriptionInput, false, new SubProgressMonitor(monitor, 50));
```

The sum of the 'tick' count given to all the sub progress monitors should match the 'tick' count given on the `beginTask` call.